# What is the general form of the solutions of the 2-electron system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, fermions

According to Sakurai the solutions of the two-electron system are of the form $\psi=\phi({\bf x_1},{\bf x_2})\chi(m_{s1},m_{s2})$

Since it's a fermionic system, $\psi$ must be a linear combination of antisymmetric states. If $\phi$ is symmetric and $\chi$ is antisymmetric (or the other way around), then $\phi\chi$ is antisymmetric, and so is a linear combination.

With no spin dependence, the Hamiltonian is $\mathcal{H}=({\bf p_1}^2 + {\bf p_2}^2)/2m$, and the spatial solutions are of the form $\omega_A({\bf x_1})\omega_B({\bf x_2})$, so $\phi$ can be written as a symmetrical and antisymmetrical combination

\begin{equation}
\phi_{\pm}({\bf x_1},{\bf x_2}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left[ \omega_A({\bf x_1})\omega_B({\bf x_2}) \pm \omega_A({\bf x_2})\omega_B({\bf x_1}) \right]
\end{equation}

In the same way, $\chi$ can be a triplet or a singlet state.

But, is every possible solution a linear combination of antisymmetric terms $\phi\chi$? I don't think so, because I found the following state

\begin{equation}
\psi = \omega_A({\bf x_1})\omega_B({\bf x_2})\chi_{+-}
- \omega_A({\bf x_2})\omega_B({\bf x_1})\chi_{-+}
\end{equation}

And I couldn't write it as a linear combination of the following:

\begin{equation}
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}[l]
&\phi_+({\bf x_1},{\bf x_2})\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \chi_{+-}-\chi_{-+} \right)\\
\phi_-({\bf x_1},{\bf x_2})
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}[l]
&\chi_{++}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \chi_{+-}+\chi_{-+} \right)\\
\chi_{--}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

The state $\psi$ is antisymmetric, and it is a valid state for the 2-electron system. But it isn't a combination of *antisymmetric* states of the form $\phi({\bf x_1},{\bf x_2})\chi(m_{s1},m_{s2})$, so these states do not form a complete basis of solutions. I would like to know a complete basis for the system.

Comment: Does Sakurai claim that states *can* be of that form (or linear combinations thereof), or that they *must* be of that form? If the latter, the claim is incorrect, but you should provide the specific wording.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty On page 453 of the 2nd edition he says: _This together with (7.3.6) implies that if the space part of the wave function is symmetrical (antisymmetrical), the spin part must be antisymmetrical (symmetrical)_. That's why I think he claims the states must be of that form, or a linear combination

Comment: The claim you quote doesn't come anywhere *near* a claim that all states 'must' be of that form, or even that they must be linear combinations of states of that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

$$ S \equiv \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\chi_{+-}-\chi_{-+}]$$

and

$$ T \equiv \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\chi_{+-}+\chi_{-+}]$$

and subbing in:

$$ \omega_A(x_1)\omega_B(x_2) = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[\phi^++\phi^-] $$

and likewise for the other $\omega$:

$$ \psi = \frac 1 2 [(\phi^+ + \phi^-)(T+S) - (\phi^+-\phi^-)(T-S)] $$

$$ \psi = \frac 1 2 [(\phi^+T + \phi^+S + \phi^-T +\phi^-S) - (\phi^+T - \phi^+S - \phi^-T +\phi^-S) ]$$

$$ \psi = \frac 1 2 [\phi^+T + \phi^+S + \phi^-T +\phi^-S - \phi^+T + \phi^+S + \phi^-T -\phi^-S ]$$

$$ \psi = \phi^+S + \phi^-T$$

which is the sum of both antisymmetric terms.